# How to simplify this PHP code?

Tags: php

Currently I'm trying this:

```
$sql_words = array("select","update","set", "from", "where", "and", "order by","insert into","delete");

echo str_replace($sql_words,
         array("<span style='color:red'>SELECT</span>","<span style='color:red'>UPDATE</span>",
          "<span style='color:green'>SET</span>", "<span style='color:green'>FROM</span>",
          "<span style='color:blue'>WHERE</span>","<span style='color:green'>AND</span>",
          "<span style='color:yellow'>ORDER BY</span>",
           "<span style='color:green'>INSERT INTO</span>",
           "<span style='color:green'>DELETE</span>"),
        $variable
        );
```

I want this to be a bit shorter and I'd like the color to be a variable.

For example: in python there are list comprehension where I would do something like this:

```
$newsql_words  = ["<span style='color:#'+randomcolor+'>'+$nice_sql_word+'</span>' for $nice_sql_word in $sql_words]
```

Any idea how to do this in php?

Comment: You're comparing two different operations.  The PHP operation is doing a replace on an existing string.  Your Python code is simply generating a list of new strings using string formatting and list comprehension - **not** replacing existing strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is nice to remove all the repeated html code and use it just when you're going to print it. so

```
foreach($sql_words as $word) {
    printf("<span style='color:%s'>%s</span>", $colors[array_rand($colors), strtoupper($word)]);
}
```

where `$sql_words` are your words and `$colors` is an array with all the colors you want to randomize.

It's the simplest thing I can come up without knowing the application of this. Hope it helps.

Comment: just one thought: `printf('<span style="color etc">'` (with inverted quoted)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you just want to add a random color to each word? This would do the job and convert them all to uppercase as well:

```
$sql_words = array("select","update","set", "from", "where", "and", "order by","insert into","delete");
$colors = array('red','green','blue','yellow');
$color_max = count($colors) - 1;
$new_sql_words = array();
foreach($sql_words as $sql_word) {
   $new_sql_words[] = "<span style='color:".$colors[rand(0,$color_max)]."'>".strtoupper($sql_word)."</span>";
}
```

As AJ notes in the comments, you shouldn't be performing a `str_replace` at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to generate a random color, here's a good link:

http://www.talkincode.com/generate-a-random-colour-with-php-170.html

```
$colour = rand(0,10000000);
$colour = dechex($colour);
```

Personally, I would generate a separate random value on the interval [0,255] for each RGB color component to guarantee I have a valid color value, e.g.:

```
$colorR = dechex(rand(0,255));
$colorG = dechex(rand(0,255));
$colorB = dechex(rand(0,255));

// Normalize the string lengths to 2
$colorR = (strlen($colorR) == 2) ? $colorR : "0" . $colorR;
$colorG = (strlen($colorG) == 2) ? $colorG : "0" . $colorG;
$colorB = (strlen($colorB) == 2) ? $colorB : "0" . $colorB;

$color = $colorR . $colorG . $colorB;
```